# Notice: Undefined index, php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I've created a form in html to create an invoice, but I'm getting the following notice when I submit my form:
Undefined index: add in /public_html/Bicycle Store/create_invoice.php on line 38

I had a missing parameter in my binding parameters and fixed it, but I'm still getting the notice when I submit.  I checked php.net, but I'm not seeing where my code violates the syntax.  Here's the php section of code that processes the inputted data:

```
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if( $_POST["add"] ) {

if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO INVOICE VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"))) {
        echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}

if (!$stmt->bind_param("sssissddd", $_POST['fname'], $_POST['lname'], $_POST['phone'], $_POST['date'], $_POST['invoice_num'], $_POST['item_num'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['discount'], $_POST['total'])) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

else {
    printf("%d row inserted.<br/>", $stmt->affected_rows);
}

$stmt->close();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your form include an input with `name='add'`?  Test if it is set.  `if (isset($_POST['add']))`

Comment: I'd perhaps highlight line 38 for some of us, there's a considerable lack of psychic talent around here :(

Comment: if any of those fields are checkboxes, they'll only be in $_POST if the checkbox was checked. but regardless, you should never assume the fields are present, and always have an isset() test first.

Comment: The discount field is a dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
if( $_POST["add"] ) {
```

with

```
if( isset($_POST["add"]) /* and other condition on $_POSt["add"] if necessary */) {
```

Problem is that you are accessing "add" key in your post array and it is not there.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it.  Unfortunately, it is still not adding the record to the database.